# move div from left to right and then stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

do you know how to move the `div.move` from left to right `1px` per second? And stop the move of the div when the div arrives to `.stop` div?

https://jsfiddle.net/z2mjvbss/4/

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="stop">
    stop
  </div>
<div class="move">
</div>
</div>

<button id="go">
go
</button>


$( "#go" ).click(function() {
  $( ".move" ).animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: "+=5000px",
    height: "toggle"
  }, 5000, function() {

  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your JS code to following

```
$( "#go" ).click(function() {
  var stop = $(".stop").offset().left;
  $( ".move" ).animate({
     opacity: 0.25,
     left: stop-($(".stop").width()+$(this).width()),
     height: "toggle"
   }, 5000, function() {}
  );
});
```

And your CSS to this

```
.content {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 10px solid green;
    background:yellow;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    padding:10px;
    position: relative;
}

.stop{
  float:right;
  background:brown;
}

.move{
  left:0;
  background:brown;
  height:100%;
  width:10px;
  opacity:0.2;
  position: absolute;
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2eLu7bje/)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is working! By the way, do you know how to put .move div in the first position after .move div arrive to .stop div?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the modified fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/z2mjvbss/6/

You can stop it at a particular location by modifying the final value of `left`.

Code for backup

```
$( "#go" ).click(function() {
  $( ".move" ).animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: "200px",
  }, 5000, function() {

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this......

HTML

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="stop">
    stop
  </div>
  <div class="move">
    move
  </div>
</div>

<button id="go">
  go
</button>
```

CSS

```
.content{float:left; width:100%;background:#FFFFFF;}
.move{float:left;width:100px;background:black;color:white;}
.stop{float:right;width:100px;background:red;}
```

JS

```
$("#go").on("click",function(){
    goOnePixelRight();
});
function goOnePixelRight(){
    var top=$(".move").offset().top;
    var left=$(".move").offset().left;
    $(".move").offset({top:top,left:left+1});
   if(parseInt($(".move").offset().left)!=parseInt($(".stop").offset().left)){
      setTimeout("goOnePixelRight();",1000);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using requestanimationframe. The below article explains it more with an example. Here it moves 7px , but you can change it to 1px.

https://link.medium.com/JrgbH9gdf8